# Error in entering data

Tags: carto

I am in the process of creating a new map. I have no problem picking a data set, however whenever I try to change any of the data under Data View, I get an error message that reads "Oops, there has been an error saving your changes."

Also, when attempting to add additional columns, I get a message saying that a new column has been created but no new column appears. I am even unable to switch the column data type to an existing column. Instead I get the message "error changing column type: undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass". Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you might need to add a bit more information. What source data, when new column type, etc.

Comment: Basically, I can't do anything. It won't let me adjust any of the information or add any new column, regardless of the type.

Comment: Check permissions for the folder where the data is located.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a cache problem. A "workaround" to avoid this is executing after any of those failed processes to "update/refresh" the dataset: `SELECT CDB_TableMetadataTouch('dataset_name');`.